# How to get real eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I construct a 100*100 matrix `k` and want to use `numpy.linalg.eig` to diagonalize it.

```
k=np.zeros((100,100))
np.fill_diagonal(k,-2)
np.fill_diagonal(k[1:,:-1],1.5)
np.fill_diagonal(k[:-1,1:],0.5)
```

when I try smaller matrix, such as

```
w,v=np.linalg.eig(k[:10,:10])
```

the eigenvalue `w` and eigenvector `v` are real. But when I try bigger matrix or the whole complete matrix

```
w,v=np.linalg.eig(k)
```

`w` and `v` turn out to be complex numbers, and the imaginary part is non-negligible.

I also try `scipy.linalg.eig`, it has similar issue.

I want to take the natural logarithm of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. There's no physical meaning of complex numbers in my model.

How can I only have independent real number eigenvalues and eigenvectors? If not, how to change the complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors to real ones by python?

Comment: Can you prove any square tri-diagonal matrix must have real eigenvalues? If you can't, there isn't much you can do.  According to wikipedia, a real symmetric tridiagonal matrix has real eigenvalues, and all the eigenvalues are distinct (simple) if all off-diagonal elements are nonzero.  Your matrix doesn't seem to fall into this category, so these are likely the eigenvalues of that matrix.  You haven't done anything wrong, and can't change that.

Comment: Interestingly, all eigenvalues are real up to the size 64 by 64. At size 65 by 65 imaginary parts appear, and they are not very small: about 0.01. Quite a sudden change, which makes me suspicious. If the eigenvalues are correct, and you don't want complex one, then the only way is to filter out those with imaginary part over some threshold (1e-16 or so).

Comment: imaginary part is large enough so that it's non-negligible. I just wonder if python can change the pairs of complex eigenvalues/vetors to real ones.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, a [Toepelitz tridiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues) (which this appears to be) should have real eignevalues if the product of the off-diagonal values is positive (in this case `0.5*1.5 = .75`)

Comment: @DanielF Good find! The eigenvectors [can also be found in closed form](http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/toep3.pdf), so the OP doesn't need NumPy's eig (which is evidently struggling here) at all.

Comment: Does it also work if the off-diagonal element is positive but not a constant? How can I find eigenvectors in closed form?

Comment: @kinderchan No, those formulas are only for constant diagonals (Toeplitz matrices). In general, there is no closed form and you need a numerical solution... which brings us back to the issue here.

Comment: @FTP I'm solving a matrix differential equation, that's why I wanna diagonalize the matrix, and I find the numerical error is big for this case, I don't know why, maybe it's for the LAPACK.

Answer (score 2):

@Daniel F and @FTP were quicker than me, see their comments, but since I have the code sitting here I may as well share it:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

def tri_toep_eig(a, b, c, n):
    evals = a + 2*np.sqrt(b*c) * np.cos(np.pi * np.arange(1, n+1) / (n+1))
    evecs = np.sin(np.outer(np.arange(1, n+1) * np.pi / (n+1),
                            np.arange(1, n+1))) \
        * np.sqrt(b/c)**np.arange(n)[:, None]
    return evals, evecs

def tri_toep(a, b, c, n):
    return sparse.dia_matrix((np.outer((b, a, c), np.ones((n,))),
                              (-1, 0, 1)), (n, n))
def check(a, b, c, n):
    evals, evecs = tri_toep_eig(a, b, c, n)
    tt = tri_toep(a, b, c, n)
    for eva, eve in zip(evals, evecs.T):
        assert np.allclose(tt @ eve, eva * eve)

check(-2, 0.5, 1.5, 100)
```

Comment: I'm a newbie about the Toepelitz tridiagonal matrix, can you explain the parameters and add some comments pls.

Comment: I happen to use the same numbers for off diagonal elements as an example, what if `b` or `c` are arrays with different values?

Comment: @kinderchan I'm afraid this only works for Toeplitz tridiagonal matrices. `a` is the value of the elements of the main diagonal, `b, c` for the two subdiagonals. `n` is the dimension. If your diagonals are not constant there may well be true complex eigenvalues, etc.

Comment: yes, but they are complex conjugate eigenvalues `a+bi` and `a-bi` pairs, and some are real, I wanna change the complex conjugate eigenvalues pairs to real ones, are there python libraries handle this problem?

Comment: @kinderchan What do you mean change them?

Comment: I'm solving a matrix differential equation, when I diagonalize the matrix (similar with the example above), it shows both real and complex conjugate eigenvalues/vectors. I wanna get the real solution.

Comment: Indeed, this doesn't solve the problem of getting correct eigenvalues from NumPy. FWIW, Octave (which is LAPACK based) returns  real (and correct within 1e-5) eigenvalues for the 100 by 100 matrix in this example. cc @kinderchan

Comment: Oh. When trying Octave, I transposed the matrix by mistake, putting 1.5 above the diagonal. This is why the eigenvalues came out right. Same happens with NumPy. Of course, transpose isn't supposed to change the eigenvalues. A LAPACK bug.

Answer (score 0):

#### Transpose fixes eigenvalues

Apparently, LAPACK hates nonsymmetric tridiagonal matrices where the larger off-diagonal elements are below the diagonal. Using the transposed matrix, in which the larger elements are above the diagonal, results in real eigenvalues. (Theoretically, a matrix and its transpose have the same eigenvalues.) In addition to being real, they agree with the [theoretical values](http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/toep3.pdf) up to sorting and reasonable errors.

```
a, b, c, n = -2, 0.5, 1.5, 100
k = np.zeros((n, n))
np.fill_diagonal(k, a)
np.fill_diagonal(k[:-1, 1:], b)
np.fill_diagonal(k[1:, :-1], c)

theory = a - 2*np.sqrt(b*c) * np.cos(np.pi * np.arange(1, n+1) / (n+1))
computed = np.sort(np.linalg.eig(k.T)[0])
print(np.max(np.abs(theory - computed)))
```

This prints `6.183001044490766e-08`, the largest discrepancy between the computed and theoretical eigenvalue. Without transposing T, this error goes up to 0.26.

#### Eigenvectors

You also wanted eigenvectors. The eigenvectors returned by `np.eig` for the transposed matrix are the *left* eigenvectors for the original matrix: that is, they satisfy `vec.dot(k) = lam*vec` instead of `k.dot(vec) = lam*vec`.  If you want to get the right eigenvectors for the original matrix, use SciPy's `eig`:

```
from scipy import linalg as la
evals, right_evects, left_evects = (np.real(_) for _ in la.eig(k.T, left=True, right=True))
```

SciPy's eigensolver is different from NumPy's in that it returns the eigenvectors and eigenvalues with `+0j` attached; it considers them complex but correctly evaluates the imaginary part to 0. I truncated that imaginary part above. Note that SciPy return order is "evals, left, right" but since k was transposed, I switched left and right around.

Let's check these eigenvectors:

```
np.max([np.linalg.norm(k.dot(vec) - ev*vec) for ev, vec in zip(evals, right_evects.T)])
```

returns `1.845213984555825e-14`, not bad. The transpose on the array with eigenvectors is because `zip` picks rows from a matrix, and we need columns.

#### Bonus content

So... problem solved? Well, I didn't say I can diagonalize your matrix. Trying to invert the matrix formed by either left or right eigenvectors looks like a losing proposition; the inverse is horrible.

Also, we should not trust the above test for eigenvectors too much. It  gave a tiny error for the *right eigenvectors*... let's try it on the *wrong eigenvectors*, those with nontrivial imaginary parts.

```
wrong_evals, wrong_evects = np.linalg.eig(k)
np.max([np.linalg.norm(k.dot(vec) - ev*vec) for ev, vec in zip(wrong_evals, wrong_evects.T)])
```

This returns `1.7136373586499598e-14`. Wrong eigenvectors are even better than the real thing!

Comment: thx a lot for your help! Anything I can do for this? Any other python package can handle this problem?

Comment: I also try to change the  [complex conjugated](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iv-first-order-systems/matrix-methods-eigenvalues-and-normal-modes/MIT18_03SCF11_s33_7text.pdf) pairs to real ones, but it doesn't narrow the error.

Comment: @FTP I think your last observation is a likely candidate to explain the 'wrong result' because this expression may well be what is minimized by the algorithm. This leaves the mystery of the switch at `n=64` which may be down to some hardcoded switch of strategy. Anynway, I'd not call it a bug, it's just numerically very tricky.

Comment: @kinderchan [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) can solve eigenproblems too, and it pays particular attention to precision, it being the focus of the library. Unfortunately, `import mpmath as mp; mp.eig(mp.matrix(k))` seems to take forever; I didn't have the patience to wait for it to return.